# How can I click on content within an iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I am trying to use Selenium to click buttons on a web page. I use this code:

```
driver.find_element(By.Xpath, '//*[@id="payments"]').click()
```

Normally this works, but it does not seem to be able to click the button shown in this HTML:

```
<iframe src="/ProviderPortal" id="main-iframe" frameborder="0" style="min-height: 600px; height: 600px;">
<a href="/ProviderPortal/Payment" id="payments">Payments</a>
</iframe>
```

When I run the code, nothing happens - it does not proceed to the next URL. The other buttons, that were successfully clicked, were not within an iframe. Is this the reason for the problem? How can I make it click successfully?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. We are not interested in your background or personal details, or your frustration with the project. We *are* interested in a *precise, clearly asked question*. What goes wrong when you try using the code, and how do you know that there is a problem? What is supposed to happen instead? What specifically is your question about this problem? Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. To diagnose the problem, we need some context - e.g., *what web page* is this?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer resolved your problem

Comment: I tried to edit the question, according to my understanding of what you are saying, to meet the site standards. Please feel free to edit again if I got something wrong. I don't understand, however, why you apparently call the `<a>` tag a "button".

Answer (score 0):

In order to access web element(s) inside an iframe you need to switch to the iframe first. Like the following:

```py
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('main-iframe'))
driver.find_element(By.Xpath, '//*[@id="payments"]').click()
```

Once you finished working inside an iframe you will have to switch out from the iframe to the default content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to switch to that iframe by:
drive.switch_to.frame(1)

Then swicth back to main content:

driver.switch_to.default_content()